# module exports property by reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, caching, ecmascript-6

I have a cache class:

```
class Cache {
    constructor() {
        this._cache = {};
    }

    refresh(cb) {
        Enums_db.find({key: {$in: ['COUNTRY_LIST', 'SUPPORTED_COUNTRIES', 'COUNTRY_DIAL']}}).exec((e, docs) => {
            _.each(docs, (doc) => {
                switch (doc.key) {
                    case 'COUNTRY_LIST':
                        this._cache.COUNTRY_LIST = doc.value;
                        break
                    case 'SUPPORTED_COUNTRIES':
                        this._cache.SUPPORTED_COUNTRIES = doc.value;
                        break;
                    case 'COUNTRY_DIAL':
                        this._cache.COUNTRY_DIAL = doc.value;
                        break;
                }
            })

            cb && cb()
        })
    }

    init(cb) {
        this.refresh(cb)
        setInterval(() => {
            this.refresh()
        }, 3000)
    }
}
module.exports = new Enums()
```

module.exports = new Enums()

Also, I have enums file:

```
const cache = require('./utils/cache')

module.exports = {
    COUNTRY_LIST: cache.cache.COUNTRY_LIST,
    SUPPORTED_COUNTRIES: cache.SUPPORTED_COUNTRIES,
    COUNTRY_DIAL: cache.COUNTRY_DIAL,
    OTHER_ENUM: []
}
```

And the print example file:

```
const {COUNTRY_LIST} = require('../enums')

setInterval(function () {
    console.log(COUNTRY_LIST)
}, 3000)
```

This way I get always the same values, even if they're refreshed and edited in the cahche class.
I've seen that if I will export only the cache, and user the print as: cache.COUNTRY_LIST then it will work. How can I solve it, so the print will only print the COUNTRY_LIST propery from the enums, and it will be accessed by ref from the cache file?

Thanks.

Comment: What is that `OTHER_ENUM` doing in there? Why do you access some things via `cache` and others via `cache.cache`?

Comment: Where do you even instantiate your `Cache`?

Comment: The `enums` object literal takes the properties out of the cache once, it's not live. The destructuring takes the property out of the object once, it's not live. And really there's no way to change that.

Comment: OTHER_ENUM is just static config enum. How can I make it 'live'?

Comment: If you want to make the object live, a) make its properties getters b) point the `new Cache` instance to it to animate it. And always refer to the object directly, don't pull its properties into constant variables.